# Run Checkstyle using Gradle on all project files

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I'd like to introduce Checkstyle rule to a Gradle project, that no file in repository can contain tab characters, including files outside source sets (like e.g. `README.md`).

I've tried with the following config:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

checkstyle {
    checkstyleMain.source = '.'
}
```

but then I get exception:

```
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'checkstyleMain' during up-to-date check.  See stacktrace for details.
Failed to create MD5 hash for file .gradle\2.7\taskArtifacts\cache.properties.lock.
```

This means that I need to exclude `.gradle` directory and most probably others like `.git` or `.idea`, but how can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure that checkstyle can run against non java files?

Comment: Yes - you even have `fileExtensions` property in Checker: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Checker

Comment: I would create a fileTree then exclude directories you don't want to be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that works for me. It analyzes all files in the project except directories like `.git`, `.idea`, `gradle`, `build` and other IntelliJ IDEA or Gradle specific autogenerated files.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '6.12.1'
}

checkstyleMain {
    source = fileTree('.') {
        excludes = ['.*/**', 'gradle*', 'build/**', '*.iml', '*.log', '**/*.jar']
    }
}
```